# how to measure distance of 2 separate objects via select faces

Tags: transforms, measurement

I am struggling to find a way to measure the vertical distance between 2 faces of 2 independent objects so that I can move the target object to the correct print-bed position for printing.
The measure tool appears to be only available for one object at a time in edit mode... Any tips?

[image]

Comment: why don't you select your target-face in edit mode, use Shift-S -> Cursor to selected, then select the other object's face and Shift-S -> Selection to Cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapping might be the way to go..

- Set 'Snap To' to 'Vertex'
- Set 'Snap With' to 'Center'
- Set your Transform Pivot to '3D Cursor'

The 'Center' Snap setting means the current transform center.. so the snap source will be wherever the 3D Cursor is at the beginning of the move. In a suitable orthogonal view...

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>-Drag will move the 3D cursor. Subsequently holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> will cause the cursor to snap to vertices.

Having established the source vertex, you can then move the object under constraint (here, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>,) and the source vertex will snap to target vertices in that dimension.

[image]